# Why was question 690388 (workstation video card pricing) closed as "too broad", and how can it be improved?

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request, specific-question

Question 690388, "[Why do workstation graphics cards cost far more than equivalent consumer graphics cards?](https://superuser.com/questions/690388/why-do-workstation-graphics-cards-cost-far-more-than-equivalent-consumer-graphic)", was closed by a moderator as *too broad*.

I can't quite see how the scope of this question is too large.  It asks a well-defined question, has received several upvotes (including one after it was closed), and is not a shopping recommendation question.  Assuming that this question genuinely is too broad, why is it so and what should I do to narrow its scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume it was closed in response to a flag.

I would agree with you that it is a reasonable question that can be answered just fine. Thus, I've reopened it.

Answer (score 2):

The first paragraph of the question mentioned something about it not being a shopping question, which wasn't brought up by any flags or any comments before that. It seemed pre-emptive for no reason.

Users upvote all sorts of things. And right now that there is a Winterbash hat given for not downvoting anything in a day, that metric yet again cannot be relied on.

Closing was not in response to any flags, but to the question being broad in scope.

There are many factors involved in pricing anything. Supply, demand, market cycle, advances in technology and production, etc. Essentially, "Why do things cost how much they cost?"

So, it was closed as being too broad.